# how is Orion context data persisted in Cosmos?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I've heard about a connector persisting Orion context data in Cosmos in order to create a historical view of such data.

What's the name of such connector and where can I find documentation about it?
What's the format of the persisted data?
Where is the data stored within Cosmos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector you are asking for is [Cygnus](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/tree/develop/flume), a Flume-based software able to receive notifications from Orion and persist them in Cosmos.

You can read a complete description and installation, configuration and usage guides within the [README](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/blob/develop/flume/README.md).

The persisted data is stored as text files in the configured Cosmos user space, i.e. a directory in HDFS such as `/user/myuser/mydataset`. For each (entity,attribute) pair received by Cygnus, a line is persisted in a text file. In Cygnus 0.1 this line is written in CSV style ('|' separator):

`ts|iso8601date|entityId|entityType|attributeName|attributeType|value`

in a text file called (a file per (entity,attribute) pair):

`/user/myuser/mydataset/entityId-entityType-attributeName-atributeType.txt`

Nevertheless, from release 0.2 (inclusive) the lines are written in Json format:

`{"ts"="xxx", "iso8601date"="xxx", "entityId"="xxx", "entityType"="xxx", "attributeName"="xxx", "attributeType"="xxx", "value"="xxx"|{...}|[...]}`

in a text file called (a file per entity):

`/user/myuser/mydataset/cygnus-myuser-mydataset-entityId-entityType.txt`

Comment: This answer explains Cygnus format for 0.1 and 0.2 versions. For newer versions (0.3, 0.4, etc.) have a look to Cygnus home page: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/tree/develop/flume