# Context history in Orion

Tags: fiware-orion

I am interested in knowing more about the context history feature of Orion, which is mentioned here:
https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE.OpenSpecification.Data.PubSub#Context_history

I cannot figure:

1. whether context history is implemented and how in the current
   ORION
2. if it is implemented, I cannot figure how to tap into it, that
   is, I don't see it covered by APIs etc.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

By design, Orion doesn't store historic data itself: its purpose is to have always the current context information view of the system. However, Orion can be easly integrated with persistence backends implementing such historic through [Cygnus](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/tree/develop/flume) (HDFS, MySQL and CKAN by the time being).

For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389904/how-is-orion-context-data-persisted-in-cosmos) explains how to use Cygnus to persist Orion context in Cosmos (HDFS-bases storage).

Comment: Do I understand correctly, then, that mean that the _context history_ functionality however described in the link I pasted in my OP, is not implemented natively within Orion itself, but only through external persistence systems like Cygnus?  (thanks for the link, BTW!!)

Comment: By the time being and up to the current Orion CB version at time of writting this (0.14.1), your understanding is correct. You're welcome! :)

Comment: Thanks again! What I find interesting is that via Cygnus you write the historical data to some other, external data storage, and I am wondering why we couldn't use also for history the same MongoDB storage that holds already the current view of context data for Orion (of course keeping current and historical data well separated). Any design rationale behind it?

Comment: The design rationale is the separation of concerns principle. However, you are right: a Cygnus sink for MongoDB could be developed (probably we will do that in some moment) and that sink could use the same MongoDB instance that Orion uses.

Comment: Hi, looking around I have also found [this](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-livedemoapp/tree/master/package/ngsi2cosmos) as a kind of connector from Orion to Cosmos. Is this a viable alternative to Cygnus, as long as Cosmos is the sink?

Comment: ngsi2cosmos is not recommended any longer, given that it is obsolete (it was the previous piece of software in charge of Orion data persistance to Cosmos, but I was replaced by Cygnus).