# do not know how to install historymod

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I find a lot of information dispersed over the Internet. There is nothing concrete. If I can guide point to point, to know what I have to install on the machine, and so to create the historical data for the statistics.

I need to make the "linear graph" widget work properly.

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: Another question, can put a real-time graph with no record?

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look into the README document available on the [github repository](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/historymod). Take into account that this file has been updated recently.

Answer (score 0):

The historymod module is part of an specific application (FIWARE LiveDemo app) and not recommended as general solution. Have a look to [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157215/context-history-in-orion) about how to persist hitorical context information comming from Orion.